# Android Studio detects random unknown device

Tags: android-studio, adb

Since everyone else is having problems getting their device recognized by ADB and Android Studio, I want to use this opportunity to breathe fresh air into this topic by having the exact opposite problem.

My Android Studio is randomly detecting a "unknown device" in the list of devices. If I run the connection troubleshooter it sometimes list an "emulator-5554" device.

> emulator-5554
>   - Device was detected by ADB but not Android Studio

The only problem is I have no physical or virtual device running on my PC. The issue started recently and it's appearing and disappearing in like a few seconds interval. I'm going crazy because I can't find the cause of the issue, and when I have my phone connected, if I click "Run" at the moment the random device appears, it will try to install it there, but it disappears again and then it just fails to install instead to install it onto my phone.

My Android Studio:

> Android Studio 3.5.1
>   Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 25, 2019
>   JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Windows 10 10.0

Comment: I have this same problem.

Comment: I actually managed to fix the problem by assigning a different port to ADB. I did it somewhere in AS Settings. Apparently there was something else using the same port on my machine, I didn't know what so this was the easiest solution.